# How to fix 'warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)' on arch

Tags: arch-linux, locale, language

I am on arch for Wsl and was having trouble opening exe applications(such as firefox) from wsl2 terminal. By running `locale -a` I found that I didn't have `en_US.UTF-8` or any other locale and only had C. I tried to generate locale by uncommenting from `etc/locale.gen` and doing `locale-gen` but got the error `warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`. I tried installing the language package with `yum -y install glibc-locale-source glibc-langpack-en` but since I didn't have yum in my system I had to install it first. However while I was installing yum I came across the same error `warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

(I am not sure whether I can ask wsl related questions on this community so if this query is not permitted please let me know)

Comment: `pacman` is the package manager of choice for Arch-based distros. How did you install it?

Comment: I installed `pacman` when I installed arch for wsl on my virtual machine.

Comment: My `/etc/locale.gen` has both en_US entries uncommented. Does the WSL install follow the Arch Wiki?

Comment: I've checked `etc/locale.gen` once more and found the problem - I had a strange line above en_US uncommented and that line was causing the error. After uncommenting again I was able to solve the issue. Thank you for the help.